# Safari - AppleScript does not move to the next section of a bookdown online book

Tags: safari, applescript, bookdown

I am writing a script to print a section of a `bookdown` [online book](https://bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/intro.html) as PDF, then move to the next section, and so on.

The print part works (the key codes are from [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript)):

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    activate
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 35 using command down -- activate print menu item
    end tell
    
    delay 0.5
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 15
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 48 -- press tab 15 times
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 49 -- press space
    end tell
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 2
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 125 -- press down key twice
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36 -- enter
    end tell
    
    set i to 0
    repeat while i < 16
        set i to i + 1
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 125 -- press tab to get to "save"
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36 -- enter to cleck on save
    end tell
    
end tell
```

**Problem**

Now that I have printed the current section and I am back on Safari, I can click manually on the right arrow and move to the next section, but I can't manage to have the script to do that.

I have tried to add the following to the script above:

```
tell application "System Events"
        key code 124 -- right arrow to enter the next page
    end tell
```

Or even to "reopen" Safari, but nothing happens.

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    activate
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 124 -- right arrow to move to the next section
    end tell
    
end tell
```

How can I have AppleScript "turn the page" and move to the next section?

Also, I welcome suggestions to improve the script! I wonder if it would be easy to avoid repeating "tab" 15 times. I have looked at the Accessibility Inspector and found that "PDF" in the print menu corresponds to `NSPopUpButtonCell`. I have tried to use `select NSPopUpButtonCell of its sheet` but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can click manually on the right arrow and move to the next section, but I can't manage to have the script to do that.
>
> How can I have AppleScript "turn the page" and move to the next section?

If you are trying to programmatically click the *right-arrow*, as shown in the image below, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can do that:

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell document 1 to ¬
        do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-angle-right')[0].click();"
```

---

**Notes:**

This requires **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be check on the hidden **Develop** menu.

To unhide the hidden **Develop** menu:

- **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** > **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar**

---

[image]

---

**Update to address:**

> Also, I welcome suggestions to improve the script! I wonder if it would be easy to avoid repeating "tab" 15 times.

Here is how I'd use the **JavaScript** from above and coded to avoid using the `key code` and or `keystroke` **System Events**  *commands*, especially **tabbing** around the **UI**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    
    tell application process "Safari"
        
        set frontmost to true
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until (its frontmost = true)
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 20 then return
        end repeat
        
        click menu item "Print…" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "File" of ¬
            menu bar 1
        
        tell its front window
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists menu button "PDF" of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click menu button "PDF" of sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists menu item "Save as PDF" of ¬
                menu 1 of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click menu item "Save as PDF" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu button "PDF" of ¬
                sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 20 then return
            end repeat
            
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1
            
            set i to 0
            repeat while (exists sheet 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 100 then return
            end repeat
            
        end tell    
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell document 1 to ¬
        do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-angle-right')[0].click();"
```

---

**Notes:**

Since this type of **AppleScript** *script* is using **UI Scripting**, I have included an *error handling* in the form of a `repeat` *loop* to wait up to two seconds for the target `UI element` to become available to be acted upon for most of the targets, however the last `repeat` *loop* waits longer because it has to wait until the **Save as PDF** to complete. A simple `delay` *command* with an appropriate *value* could be used instead, but with the include delay of a tenth of a second in the `repeat` *loops* it shouldn't have to wait any longer than need be. In other words, I'd only use simple `delay` *command* if I want to slow the *script* down from going through the various events of the **UI**. It's doubtful that it would need to be adjusted, but obviously do so as/if necessary.

If the *timeout* is reached, the *script* aborts at that point without any error message. The single-line `if i ≥ 20 then return` *statements* can be turned into a full `if` *block* and include an error message via the **display dialog**, **display alert**, or **display notification** *command* as wanted.

Comment: @Emy, Please see the **Update to address:** _section_ of my updated answer, as it address the first sentence of the last paragraph of your OP.

Comment: @Emy, I changed the last `repeat` _loop_ as it originally targeted the wrong `UI element`. It's now coded to give time for the **Save to PDF** to complete, as I noticed some of the chapters are quite long and could have been truncated. Sorry!